# MSBuild - Cannot open include file (despite listed in the INCLUDE list )

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I am probably missing something obvious - but I have been stuck for a while on this issue. I am compiling a Visual Studio project on the command line using MSBuild. Basically like this:

```
CALL vcvars32.bat
MSBuild myproject.sln /m /t:rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /verbosity:m
```

But this gives me an error: `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file 'winsock.h': No such file or directory`

But if I check the environment variable `INCLUDE`after the vcvars32.bat call the directory containing 'winsock.h' is in the list - so I definitely have this file in the SDK.

In addition if I change verbosity of MSBuild to detailed I can see the full compile command used. If I copy that and run it in the console the same cpp file compiles without any problem.

Any idea whats different inside the MSBuild context ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it, adding `/p:useenv=true` make MSBuild use the INCLUDE environment variable.

( Still a bit unsure why that had to be done though, since I can't recall having needed that earlier for command line builds. )

Comment: Based on this article, set the UseEnv property to true to guarantee that the environment variables are not overridden. Do you override environment variable?

Comment: @s09 Not on purpose at least, I simply run those two commands in a fresh cmd.

Comment: Could you reproduce that issue with a new project? Provide detail steps here (include command)